# Additional views to Django Rest Framework ViewSet

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I've got simple DRF ViewSet for a model, located at `/gen_req/`

```
class GenerationRequestViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = GenerationRequest.objects
    serializer_class = GenerationRequestSerializer
```

It has default POST/GET/etc. handlers. However, I want to add another one for GET as well for different url patter (`/gen_req/created_list`:

```
class GenerationRequestViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = GenerationRequest.objects
    serializer_class = GenerationRequestSerializer

    @action(methods=['get'])
    def special_get_handler(self, request):
        queryset = GenerationRequest.filter(...) # Some extra filtering here
        serializer = self.get_serializer(queryset, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

Is there a way to create such view within the ViewSet or another APIView should be created?

Comment: `@action(methods=['get'])` change this line to `@action(methods=['get'], url_path='created_list')` then you have `/gen_req/created_list/` route if you register this viewset.

Comment: That's exactly what I need, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it, just add such record to your `urls.py` file.

```
path('/gen_req/created_list',
     GenerationRequestViewSet.as_view({'get': 'special_get_handler'}),),
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do that, but you need to name your method accordingly. So with code, you've posted you will be able to get this method by requesting `/gen_req/special_get_handler`.

Of course, it should be registered in url.py. Smth like:

```
api_router = DefaultRouter()
api_router.register("gen_req", GenerationRequestViewSet)
```